# How to convert this sql script in linq to entity?

Tags: sql, entity-framework-4

```
SELECT * INTO #Loc1
FROM LocaleStringResource
Where LanguageId = 1

SELECT * INTO #Loc2
FROM LocaleStringResource
Where LanguageId = 3

SELECT   Loc1.Id, Loc1.LanguageId, Loc1.ResourceName, Loc1.ResourceValue,
         Loc2.Id, Loc2.LanguageId, Loc2.ResourceName, Loc2.ResourceValue
FROM         #Loc1 AS Loc1 INNER JOIN
                      #Loc2 AS Loc2 ON Loc1.ResourceName = Loc2.ResourceName
```

**Update:**
I have a table named - LocaleStringResource.
Columns: Id, LanguageId, ResourceName, ResourceValue,

Suppose I have 2 language in my system.

```
Id  Language
1   English
3   Bangla

Id  LanguageId        ResourceName                ResourceValue
1   1                 Admin.Address               Address
2   1                 Admin.Phone                 Phone
51  3                 Admin.Address               SpAddress
51  3                 Admin.Phone                 SpPhone
```

By ResourceName i get what the value is for choosen language. So from admin page i want to see for by ResourceName what are ResourceValue for both languages.

So I need a resultset which returns something like this.

```
ResourceName           ResourceValue As EnglishText       ResourceValue As SpanishText
Admin.Address          Address                            SpAddress
Admin.Phone            Phone                              SpPhone
```

Comment: you need to show what you have already tried if you want some help.

Answer (score 2):

```
        var loc1 = Context.ObjectSet<LocaleStringResource>.Where(r => r.LanguageId == 1);
        var loc2 = Context.ObjectSet<LocaleStringResource>.Where(r => r.LanguageId == 2);
        var result = (
                        from l1 in loc1
                        join l2 in loc2 on l1.ResourceName equals l2.ResourceName 
                        select new{
                            ResourceName = l1.ResourceName,
                            EnglishText = l1.ResourceValue,
                            SpanishText = l2.ResourceValue
                        }
            ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Entity framework doesn't support temporary tables and `SELECT INTO` construction so you cannot directly convert it. You must go through the logic of your application and change it so that it can be used with EF or you must wrap this code into stored procedure and call it from EF (btw. you will have to use column aliases for result set because column names must not be the same when used with EF).